# when i use the c++ string in my code it compiles but i don't show an output

Tags: c++

I don't know whether I have installed `cygwin` wrong or what but the code compiles fine but it doesn't show the output. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    string name;
    cout << "Enter the name of the person" << endl;
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Name is: " << name << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Here's the compilation image and the execution:

[image: Code Compilation]

Comment: That code looks fine and works perfectly well here: http://cpp.sh/

Comment: I will not even spend time on clicking on that link; show the compiler invocation and output here in text form, please.

Comment: Look at `cat Main.cpp` to make sure that you're compiling the file you've been editing. Also make sure that you've saved. I've lost count of how many times I've made those two errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, you use `cygwin`. I had the same issue with `gcc 5.2`. Try to install `gcc 4.9` and all corresponding libraries for this version instead.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked when i installed g++ 4.9.3

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine. The correct way to call the executable using Cygwin is `./string.exe`

Comment: In cygwin `exe` is not necessary. Just checked.